# ArrayList Collections error: which part of my code is wrong?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I would be required to write an array list of Mobile, do some operations such as add, remove, update and display. However, when it comes to sorting objects in arraylist, I am a little bit confused.

I am talking and referring to https://beginnersbook.com/2017/08/comparator-interface-in-java/

In drive class

```
    //Create an arraylist of Mobile
    ArrayList<Mobile> themobile = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to Mobile");
    System.out.println("Please select a number in the following: ");

    while (true) {  
        //A list of options 
        System.out.println("1. Diplay the next mobile.");
        System.out.println("2. Display the previous mobile.");
        System.out.println("3. Add a new mobile.");
        System.out.println("4. Remove a new mobile");
        System.out.println("5. Update a mobile.");
        System.out.println("0. Exit");

        //prompt user input
        int choice = input.nextInt();

        switch(choice) {
            case 1:
                //displayNext(themobile);
                break;
            case 2:
                //displayPrevious(themobile);
                break;
            case 3:
                addMobile(themobile);
                break;
            case 4:
                removeMobile(themobile);
                break;
            case 5: 
                updateMobile(themobile);
                break;
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Thank you for using a Mobile arraylist");
                System.exit(0);

        }
    }

    Collections.sort((themobile, new MobileByBrandName());
    System.out.println("Sorted by brand name" + themobile);

    Collections.sort(themobile, new MobileByMoNum());
    System.out.println("Sorted by brand name" + themobile);

    Collections.sort(themobile, new MobileByInS());
    System.out.println("Sorted by brand name" + themobile);

}
```

In mobile class

```
public class Mobile implements Comparable<Mobile> {
    private String brandName;
    private int modelNumber;
    private int internalMemoryS;
    private int noOfAvailCameras;

    public Mobile() {
    }

    public Mobile(String brandName, int modelNumber, int internalMemoryS, int noOfAvailCameras) {
        this.brandName = brandName;
        this.modelNumber = modelNumber;
        this.internalMemoryS = internalMemoryS;
        this.noOfAvailCameras = noOfAvailCameras;
    }

    public String getBrandName() {
        return this.brandName;
    }

    public void setBrandName(String brandName) {
        this.brandName = brandName;
    }

    public int getModelNumber() {
        return this.modelNumber;
    }

    public void setModelNumber(int modelNumber) {
        this.modelNumber = modelNumber;
    }

    public int getInternalMemoryS() {
        return internalMemoryS;
    }

    public void setInternalMemoryS(int internalMemoryS) {
        this.internalMemoryS = internalMemoryS;
    }

    public int getNoOfAvailCameras() {
        return noOfAvailCameras;
    }

    public void setNoOfAvailCameras(int noOfAvailCameras) {
        this.noOfAvailCameras = noOfAvailCameras;
    }

    public int compareTo(Mobile m) {
        return this.brandName.compareTo(m.getBrandName());
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Brand name: " + brandName + "Model number: " + modelNumber + "Internal memory space: " + internalMemoryS + "No of available cameras: " + noOfAvailCameras;
    }
}
```

Each method has its own class & import java.util.*;

```
public class MobileByMoNum implements Comparator<Mobile> {
    public int compare(Mobile m1, Mobile m2) {
        return m1.getModelNumber() - m2.getModelNumber();
    }
}

public class MobileByBrandName implements Comparator<Mobile> {
    public int compare(Mobile m1, Mobile m2) {
        return m1.getBrandName().compareTo(m2.getBrandName());
    }
}

public class MobileByInS implements Comparator<Mobile> {
    public int compare(Mobile m1, Mobile m2) {
        return m1.getInternalMemoryS() - m2.getInternalMemoryS();
    }
}
```

Outcome:

```
TestMobile.java:48: error: unreachable statement
    Collections.sort(themobile, new MobileByBrandName());
    ^
1 error
```

Any help and clarification is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: We can't see the actual code in which `Collections.sort(themobile)` actually appears.  Most likely, this line of code is not logically reachable, based on what logic you do have in your code.

Comment: Which is why I would like to know what part of my logic is doing wrong.

Comment: Please post the whole method in which you have this line `Collections.sort(themobile, new MobileByBrandName());`

Comment: I am referring to this https://beginnersbook.com/2017/08/comparator-interface-in-java/

Comment: @Simone001 Your problem has nothing to do with `Comparable`  It is to do with breaking our of your loop.

Answer (score 1):

As this code

```
while (true) {
```

never exits, the code below this loop is unreachable

Maybe `System.exit(0);` should maybe only be breaking the `while` loop.

**Note** `break` in a `switch` will not break the `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

The code after `while` loop is never reached. You need to write some logic to break out of the while loop. One easy way to fix this is:

```
int choice = -1;
while (choice != 0) {
    choice = input.nextInt();
    switch (choice) {
        //...other cases
        case 0:
            System.out.println("Thank you for using a Mobile arraylist");
    }
}
Collections.sort(...);
System.out.println(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put these lines inside while loop

```
Collections.sort((themobile, new MobileByBrandName());
System.out.println("Sorted by brand name" + themobile);

Collections.sort(themobile, new MobileByMoNum());
System.out.println("Sorted by brand name" + themobile);

Collections.sort(themobile, new MobileByInS());
System.out.println("Sorted by brand name" + themobile);
```

Also you can simplify the operation of comparison by using `Comparator.comparing` available from java 8 onwards. Like:

```
Comparator<Mobile> comparator = Comparator.comparing(new Function<Mobile,
    @Override
    public String apply(Mobile t) {
        return t.getBrandName();
    }
}).thenComparingInt(new ToIntFunction<Mobile>() {

    @Override
    public int applyAsInt(Mobile t) {
        return t.getModelNumber();
    }
}).thenComparingInt(new ToIntFunction<Mobile>() {
    @Override
    public int applyAsInt(Mobile t) {
        return t.getInternalMemoryS();
    }
});

Collections.sort(themobile, comparator);
```